# `make4ht`: when using Computer Concrete, getting `dvips: Font ... not found; characters will be left blank`

Tags: dvips, make4ht

For this problem, I am using the following MnWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=18pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}
\date{}

\maketitle


\section{Section One}

Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
    \begin{equation}
        x + y = 3
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

My build script is:

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex()
else
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
  Make:htlatex()
end
Make:image("png$", "dvipng -bg Transparent -T tight -o ${output}  -pp ${page} ${source}")
Make:match("html$",process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
```

My style config file is:

\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{font-size:1.5em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

The full errors are:

```
System call: dvips -E -q -Ppdf -f test_article.idv -pp 2 > zztest_article.ps
dvips: Font xccmi10 not found; characters will be left blank.
dvips: Font ccr10 not found; characters will be left blank.
System return: 0
System call: rungs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=test_article0x.png -r110x110 -dEPSCrop -dBackgroundColor=16#ffffff -dTextAlphaBits=2 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=2 -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE zztest_article.ps -c quit
System return: 0
System call: if exist zztest_article.ps DEL zztest_article.ps >nul
System return: 0
```

Indeed, as suggested by the error messages, no math is shown.

If instead, I use `lmodern` font, then the math shows, but surprisingly, the math quality isn't so great.

Both the drop in quality and the issue with `concmath` didn't exist before updating to the latest version of `make4ht` on GitHub.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error log:

```
System call: dvips -E -q -Ppdf -f test_article.idv -pp 2 > zztest_article.ps
dvips: Font xccmi10 not found; characters will be left blank.
dvips: Font ccr10 not found; characters will be left blank.
System return: 0
```

it seems that your build file isn't used, as `dvips` instead of `dvipng` is called. `dvips` has obviously problem with `concmath`, `dvipng` seems to work. Try to include the build file explicitly with

```
make4ht -e buildfilename.mk4 -c configfile filename.tex
```

result:

[image]

Comment: One thing that's a curiosity to me is that now `\LaTeX` isn't rendered correctly -- I am not sure why! Even if I switch back to `lmodern`, I still have that issue. It used to work fine before, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UMiKO.png -- anyway, not a big issue, so I am not going to make a question about it :p

Comment: @user89 it is probably also caused by the font size change. I would redefined it like `\def\LaTeX{LaTeX}` it doesn't look good in HTML anyway